# __str__ returned non-string (type float)

Tags: python, django

Although there are many questions of this type, but none of them is of type float.
I am trying to send a float value to my django template.

`models.py`:

```
class BudgetInfo(models.Model):
    items= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cost= models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True)
    date_added= models.DateField()
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cost
```

`views.py` (after logged in redirecting it to the this view):

```
def app_view(request):
    budget_qs=BudgetInfo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    budget=budget_qs[0]
    return render(request,'tasks_notes/index.html',{'budget':budget})
```

`index.html` using budget:

```
 <div class="container center">
 <h3 class='center'>Your total budget is: <span style="color:green;">{{ budget|floatformat:"-2" }}</span> dollars</h3>
```

I am getting an error of this type:

```
__str__ returned non-string (type float)
```

highlighting the second line of the html mentioned here.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: *Don't* return a `float` from `__str__`?

Comment: Did you read the error message and your `__str__` method ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__str__ must always return string

Seems this helps you

```
  def __str__(self):
     return str(self.cost)
```